# BigQuery Request Timed out error on script

Tags: google-bigquery, request-timed-out

We are getting an error when running a query job on BigQuery :

> 'message' => 'Request timed out. Please try again.', 
>       'reason' => 'timeout',  
>       'location' => 'script'

We will be running it again as it requested, but since it takes 1/2 hour for it to time out, it would be helpful if we knew what the problem is so we can avoid it.

Specifically:

- What does "script" mean in this context? Is it the SQL-query or one
  of the UDFs? (the query calls 3 UDFs).
- The exact same query failed twice already with "`internal error`". The "`request timed out`" was its 3rd attempt at mocking us. Any correlation between the two error types?

It would be really helpful to receive more detailed information on what failed to work, so that we can track it down.

Comment: Please provide a job id, maybe some engineer will be able to check it internally, and submit also on public issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list

Comment: Job ID: academic-diode-113417:advan_query_job_832176856c9c52fedb7ef552680457199a7f9c202 and also added it to the issue tracker you suggested

Comment: Hi, thanks for the issue report.  I have some changes that should be deployed this week that will allow us to better triage some instances of "Internal Error" messages.  If your queries are taking a long time to run, then the internal errors and timeouts are likely correlated.  I'll investigate further after my updates are pushed to production.